# How to save python data and then read it again in another python notebook?

Tags: python, database, csv, file

In order not to have to run a python code several times, I want to do it once and store the data in a file. Then I want to open another code in python and be able to call these files and work with the lists and matrices that will be saved in it.

I've tried doing something like this. I saved the data in `.csv` files using the commands

```
with open(path + '/data_robs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
     fieldnames = ['Fobs', 'Sobs', 'Hobs']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
     writer.writeheader()
     for i in range(len(Fobs)):
         writer.writerow({'Fobs': Fobs[i], 'Sobs': Sobs[i], 'Hobs': Hobs[i]})
```

So, in another notebook I defined the file so that it can be called like this:

```
data_robs = pd.read_csv(path + str("\\") + str("data_robs.csv"))
```

But when I try to fame one of the columns of this file, the program gives an error. I do `data_robs[0]` and this appears on the screen

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data_robs[0]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

The data is printed like this:

[image]

Could it be that the way I'm saving the data doesn't put it in a way that it can be called again? How can I improve this?

Comment: Please post the *full error message including the stack trace* as **text**

Comment: Also, the data seems to have been written fine.  For a dataframe, indexing it directly indexes *the columns*, there is no `0` column, your columns are `"Fobs"`, `"Sobs"` and `"Hobs"`.